# Overriding .init in custom type in D

Tags: data-structures, d

I remember having read somewhere that it's possible to override the .init property of custom types in D. I'd like to do this for a struct I've created, but I'm not finding any way to do this, especially since default constructors aren't allowed. Is this actually possible, and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Wait, default constructors aren't allowed?

Comment: Arbitrary parameterless constructors for `struct`s aren't allowed in D, because every variable is default-initialized (struct types as well), and the initializer must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can specify the init values of the fields (with compile time vars only)

```
struct foo{
    int a=0;
    real b = 5.0;
}
```

`foo.init` will then be equal to `foo(0,5.0)`

Comment: Thanks ratchet freak, I had no idea it was that easy!